# magento2 login not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, frontend, login

I tried to login magento2 account but it redirects to the frontend login page in chrome and tries to login firefox it's redirected to the empty page. 
Please help me, anyone.

Comment: are there any messages at all when it redirects you? and or if you look in console is there a javascript error? additionally have you been working on anything before this happened that could have caused it?

Comment: Nothing display in the console

Comment: Are you working on localhost ?

Comment: Check server log or enable error log in index.php or check core  config data table with secure,unsecure path and values

Comment: customer login is working firefox but still not working in chrome